# Getting all the configurations and platforms from a solution(in C# code)

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, projects-and-solutions, microsoft.build

I'm developing some compiling tool.
I'm using Microsoft.Build libraries for compile solution by selected configuration:

```
 string projectFileName = @"D:\MySolution.sln";  
 ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
 Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
 GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Mixed Platforms");                
 BuildRequestData BuidlRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
 BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
```

How can I get all the options of configuration and platform from solution file instead of just written `Debug` and `Mixed` Platform?

Thanks

Comment: does `"All Configurations"` and `"Any CPU"` work for you?

Comment: For example... But if i create a new Configuration on the solution called "dudu" I want to get it too.